# correct usage of "min" within validating a symfony choice form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, multiple-choice

As described under the book http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#min 
I would like to use the "min" options to validate a choice with must have at least one selected checkbox in it

The form looks like

```
->add('usergroups', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Group','property' => 'name','required' => true, 'multiple'  => true, 'expanded'  => true))
```

My validation.yml looks liek:

```
Pr\UserBundle\Entity\User:
constraints:
//...
properties:
    //.....
    locations:
        - Length:
            min: 7 { message: "Please select at least one group." }
```

I am totally wrong doing this, but the book won't tell me any more helpful so I ask you.
OR do I have to use True/False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the Length constraint rather than the choice.

You should be using it like..

```
Pr\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
    //...
    properties:
        //.....
        locations:
            - Choice:
                min: 7
                minMessage: "Please select at least one group."
```

All of the options that are featured on that page would be in a single level array like

```
- Choice: { min: 7, minMessage: 'message' }
```

or

```
- Choice:
    min: 7
    minMessage: 'message'
```

Comment: Cool, that exactly what I want to use. Can I also use Count? Its nearly the same isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know. I would generally (and possibly incorrectly) go for a choice and count constraints (for specifying options and count, respectively) just because it's more obvious to me what I'm validating against on each part at a later date.

Comment: well,  I think count is my favorite option :) It works perfectly. thx a lot.

Comment: This didn't help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766535/symfony2-choice-field-validation-not-working